# SQLite python command not working

Tags: python, sqlite

I am fairly new to python and am writing a code to read imagery and insert them into an SQLite database but I get the following error

```
cur.execute(statement, (index,fullpath,filename)) 
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "index": syntax error.
```

What is it that I am getting wrong? The following is the code:

```
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(basedir):
    print 'root is ' + root
    for filename in filenames:
        ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[1].lower() #extension as lowercase
            if ext == extension:
                index = filename[:9] #tile ID
            filebase = os.path.splitext(filename)[0] #first part of filename
                fullpath = os.path.join(root,filebase) + ext #build up path again
                statement = "INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES " % (table,columns) + "(%s,%s,%s);"
                cur.execute(statement, (index,fullpath,filename))
            print 'catalog entry: ' + index + ', ' + fullpath
```

Answer (score 4):

It's not `%s` in your SQL prepared statements, it's `?`.

```
statement = "INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES (?, ?, ?);" % (table,columns)
```

Also, you can define `statement` far earlier in your code (before the walk) and just reuse it.

Answer (score 2):

First, the name index  is reserved by SQLite ( [SQLite: create Index](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html) ).

Then you need to review the string formatting in Python ( see for example [Python String Format](http://mkaz.com/solog/python-string-format) )

What you want is, in SQL (index is renamed ind):

```
'INSERT INTO bbi_catalog_aug2012 (ind,path,filename) VALUES ("...","...","....");'
```

In Python with the older "%" string formatter:

```
statement = "INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES (%s,%s,%s);" %(table,columns,1,2,3)
```

or with the new string.format()

```
 statement = "INSERT INTO {0} ({1}) VALUES ({2},{3},{4});".format(table,columns,1,2,3)
```

and the result is:

```
'INSERT INTO bbi_catalog_aug2012 (ind,path,filename) VALUES (1,2,3);'
```

So your script:

```
conn = sqlite.connect("ngi.sqlite")
with conn:
    cur = conn.cursor()
     for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(basedir):
      print 'root is ' + root
      for filename in filenames:
          ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[1].lower()
          if ext == extension:
                 index = filename[:9]
                 filebase = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
                 fullpath = os.path.join(root,filename)
                 statement = "INSERT INTO {0} ({1}) VALUES ('{2}','{3}','{4}');".format(table,columns,index,fullpath,filebase)
                 cur.execute(statement)
```

The problem of replacing string formating by ? is not important here:

> Usually your SQL operations will need to use values from Python variables. You shouldn’t assemble your query using Python’s string operations because doing so is insecure; it makes your program vulnerable to an SQL injection attack ([1.13. sqlite3](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) )

Answer (score 1):

I think:

```
 if ext == extension
```

should be:

```
 if ext == "extension"
```

unless extension is a variable set further up.  If the latter then perhaps check what it is set to using a print statement.